# jQueryUI dialog: resize interfering with scroll down arrow

Tags: jquery-ui, scrollbar, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-ui-resizable

In an application I'm developing, I pop up Help in a modal jQueryUI dialog. For the most part, it works beautifully. There is one problem: if you try to use the arrow on the lower right of the dialog to scroll the help text, you can't, because it is in the same place as the mouse-drag resize for the dialog.

[image: Screen capture, for anyone having difficulty envisioning this. The issue is at lower right of dialog]

I realize this would not happen if I used the jQueryUI dialog "button" option to add a "Close" button at the bottom of the dialog, but that would be inconsistent with our style elsewhere in the application.

Anyone know a reasonable way around this? Ideally, I'd like something that would give me a small non-scrolled div at the bottom of this dialog, without affecting other dialogs, so that the mouse-drag resize would fall lower on the screen than the down-arrow.

Comment: I'm aware that I could remove the resizing handle at lower right, but that is undesirable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a bottom padding to the `ui-dialog` class in your `jquery-ui.xxxx.css` should result in the behavior you want:

```
.ui-dialog {
    ... Existing CSS...
    padding-bottom: 15px !important;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't meet the criterion of "without affecting other dialogs", but I suppose it can be adapted so that it only applies to this dialog. I'll try that.

Comment: Indeed. Added `$(this).parents('.ui-dialog').css('padding-bottom', 15)` to the dialog's `open` function member.

Comment: Yeah from the 5 minutes I spent searching there doesn't seem to be a more elegant way to obtain the .ui-dialog element without searching up from your content element.

Comment: Agreed. Static css has no way to narrow elements down by what other element they contain.

I hadn't thought of padding doing the trick; that was the key piece you gave me.